# JQuery: Select dropdown which relates to another dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**UPDATED**
I have 2 dropdowns (input select) - one for countries (*#label-country*), another - for states (*#label-state*).
Once user selects country - list of states changes.
Following code changes list of states, once country is selected:

```
$('#label-country').change(function() {
    var countryinput = $('#label-country').val();
    $.post('func/region.php', {countryinput:countryinput}, function(states) { 
        $('#label-state option').remove();
        $('#label-state').append(states);
    });
});
```

It works fine, if user manually selects country and then state for that country.
But in some occasions I want to be able to preselect country and state.

I found out that following code doesn't work - country is selected as needed, but state - not:

```
$('#label-country').val('US').trigger('change');
$('#label-state').val('Alaska');
```

Flow which I have in mind:

1. US is selected by using following line

> $('#label-country').val('US')

2. Trigger change function

> .trigger('change')

3. Select "Alaska" state by using

> $('#label-country').val('Alaska')

In the end I have:

1. Country is selected
2. List of states is changed
3. **State is not selected**

Am I missing something in sequence of change function and state selection?

Comment: Can you clarify what "doesn't work"?

Comment: 1. I change country using following code $(`#label-${idlabel}`).val(fetcheddata[idlabel]).trigger('change'); After that my second dropdown changes list of states, which is related to selected country. But second attempt of using $(`#label-${idlabel}`).val(fetcheddata[idlabel]).trigger('change');  for state doesn't work. So state is not selected and always shows first state in the list

Comment: what is `fetcheddata`? Also, I still don't understand what it is you want to happen when the user selects a state?

Comment: The code isn't quite clear because you put 2 different blocks.. I'm just guessing here, but seems like "fetcheddata[idlabel]" is falsy when idLabel is "state", meaning that there is no fetcheddata.state. Can't be sure though.

Comment: I have updated my question, sorry for confusion by showing only a part of the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#label-country').val('US').trigger('change');` is triggering a event where has an asynchronous ajax post function, which is the exact cause of your issue.

Not until the ajax `.done()` function triggered, your next line `$('#label-state').val('Alaska');` has already been called, by the time it happens, your `$('#label-state')` hasn't got a value yet, to prove this, you can use a for loop to log its values.

So all you need to do, in this case, is to put something like

`if(countryInput=="US") $('#label-state').val('Alaska');` inside of `$.post` function, and remove `$('#label-country').val('US').trigger('change');`.